# Protobuf-net 282: Is it possible to auto generate ToString() for .proto files

Tags: protobuf-net

Is it possible to get ToString() autogenerated ?

If not any tips on cutting down on manual creation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

and what would you have `.ToString()` *do*?

But sure, the template files are fully editable - see csharp.xslt; just add any code you feel like having, and you're done. Another approach would be to use a `partial class` in your own code.

Comment: I am thinking of a ToString() like:

    toString() {
         var builder = new StringBuilder();
         builder.appendLine("<<CLASSNAME>> {");
         // and for each field something like                
         builder.append([field1Name=");
         builder.append(field1Name);
         builder.append([field2Name=");
         builder.append(field2Name);
         builder.appendLine("}");
         return builder.toString();
 }
The partial class approach creates a dependency between ToString and the proto definition. We have large numbers of proto, some of which have large num of fields

Comment: @Aidan I'm just not sure why you wouldn't just run that through a JSON Serializer...

Comment: protocol buffers has been mandated as part of the architecture

Comment: @Aidan you misunderstand me: your `ToString()` basically seems to be so similar to JSON that it would suffice - I'm not on about DTO serialization here, just the ToString()